# Interpolation of time series data

Tags: time-series, interpolation, splines

I am working on using cubic spline interpolation in time series data. I used Galdolfo and Prachowney algorithms. Now how do I obtain estimates of models of cubic spline?

Comment: I find your question at the end unclear. What is it you want to obtain, exactly? What do the implementation of algorithms you mention give you?